# How to use bluetooth in Marmalade SDK?

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, marmalade

I'm writing a mobile application on Marmalade SDK. How can I connect to other device via bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/7285/bluetooth-support.html

> No, Marmalade doesn't have a Bluetooth API. However, you could write
>   an extension to do it.
>
> iOS has a CoreBluetooth API that allows you to interact with devices
>   supporting the Bluetooth 4 Low Energy GATT profile - this is only
>   supported from iOS 5/iPhone 4S/iPad3 and up, and will only
>   interoperate with Bluetooth 4 LE capable peripherals exposing a GATT
>   service. For earlier iOS devices, the only option is to use Apple's
>   proprietary iAP protocol, which means you can't "talk" to generic
>   Bluetooth devices - only those that implement iAP.
>
> Android on the other hand offers Bluetooth 2.x + EDR connectivity. A
>   number of profiles (e.g. RFCOMM, A2DP) are supported. However, Android
>   doesn't have an API for Bluetooth 4 LE yet.
>
> So, currently, the situation, from a cross-platform point of view, is
>   quite fragmented and it isn't straightforward to implement a
>   one-size-fits all Bluetooth connectivity solution.

Comment: I know this is a bit of an old post, but need some help with this. I have made an extension and am trying to bring in CoreBluetooth. I modified the mkf file in my extension in the iPhone section. I uncommended out the iphone-link-opts line and put CoreBluetooth after the -frameworks part. I am still getting linker errors when I try to deploy / build the iPhone app. Ideas?

Comment: @user856232 please, ask a new question on SO.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893384/marmalade-for-ios-with-corebluetooth